# java running problem with command java -cp

Tags: java

I am trying to add a dependent library when running the java code like:

```
javac -cp "/temp/package.jar" myRunningCode.java
java -cp "/temp/package.jar" myRunningCode
```

The first line compiling works well.

But the 2nd line gave me the error message:

`Error: Could not find or load main class myRunningCode`'

So anyone can help me with this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-could-not-find-load-main-class) this will help you to understand

Comment: When you specify '-cp' it will not include '.' by default. You can include it by adding :. to your classpath.

Comment: @matt Yes, that's what I want! Thanks a lot for your help!